# performSegueWithIdentifier Not Working - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I am trying to initiate a segue after a user has successfully created an account. I know that the function is being called, but the segue is not performed. I've attempted to use a presentViewController as an alternative and also tried the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) method. Here's the code that I think should work.

```
func showGoalViewController () {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_SetGoalViewController") as! SetGoalViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

}
```

And here's a screenshot of the segue I'm trying to call in storyboard:

[image]

Comment: `showGoalViewController()` is not working?

Comment: I believe the question is in reference to `navigateToMainAppScreen()` not working.

Comment: Is this `LoginViewController` being instantiated from the storyboard containing the "ShowSetGoal" segue?

Comment: In storyboard you need to embed your `LoginViewController` with `NavigationController`

Comment: i also think it beause segue.kind , try with something diffrent or use a NavigationController

Comment: set segue kind to `Modal`. Use segue kind `push` when your view controller had  `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you can't push view controller without UINavigationController. Please put UINavigationController or please set segue Kind "Modal" not "Push"

Comment: 3 hours of debugging later.... XCode should really provide a warning that this is the case.